# Return dynamic SQL table from function or stored procedure to use in a query

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have a number of tables that have a "Deleted" field of type DATETIME that I use to mark records as deleted (instead of totally deleting them).

I often find myself requesting data from these tables and wanting to exclude the deleted records. What I am doing right now is something like:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM [TargetTable] WHERE (Deleted IS NULL)) AS A
WHERE (.........)
```

Is it possible to have a stored procedure/function to which I can pass the table name and have the filtered table returned? Something like:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM fnExcludeDeleted('MyTable') AS A
WHERE (.........)
```

I tried doing it using a table valued function but from what I could gather, I would need to define the resulting table's columns. I cannot do this because it is not always the same table that I am using the function on.

Comment: You could do this with an SP and dynamic SQL, but what's wrong with adding the clause `DELETE IS NULL` to your queries...

Comment: Or use views to do the same thing. Which you might also consider indexing.

Comment: @Larnu I am not familiar enough with SPs to know how to do it. And couldn't find how to do it because I am not sure what to ask for.

Comment: Personally I suggest you don't. Write your very short `WHERE` clause when you need it.

Comment: @SMor I cannot indexing the views because if i try to use the "WITH SCHEMABINDING" I get an error reading "Syntax '*' is not allowed in schema-bound objects." If I don't use "WITH SCHEMABINDING", I would not be able to index the view.

Answer (score 0):

In my thought, you can not do this with table-valued functions because they need to static table declarations. Unfortunately, your tables declarations are not same. As a result you can not achieve this with help of the table-valued functions. In the following  stored procedure that may help to overcome your issue.

This stored procedure based on the below steps;

1. Generate the declared table script
2. Create a global temporary, that is formed with the same structure to the declared
   table
3. Populate the original table data to a temporary table
4. Return the result set of the temporary table

**Note:** This query uses [GetTableCreateScript](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/generate-table-defination-in-sql-server-without-gui)  stored procedure in order getting the declared table creation script.

**EDITED:** `STRING_AGG` removed for lower version of the **SQL Server 2017** and added the `XML PATH` in order to combine the rows.

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TargetTable1
GO
CREATE TABLE TargetTable1 (Col1 INT , Deleted DATE)
GO
---Populating test data---
INSERT INTO TargetTable1 VALUES (1,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO TargetTable1 VALUES (2,NULL)
INSERT INTO TargetTable1 VALUES (3,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO TargetTable1 VALUES (4,NULL)
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROC DynamicSQL 
@TableName AS VARCHAR(200)
AS
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  ##TempDynamic
DECLARE @SQLDynamicTable AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLDynamicRows AS VARCHAR(MAX)
CREATE TABLE #DynamicSQL (S VARCHAR(MAX))


INSERT INTO #DynamicSQL
EXEC    [dbo].GetTableCreateScript @TableName --->Generate Table Definition
---You can find GetTableCreateScript  create script https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/generate-table-defination-in-sql-server-without-gui

--SELECT @SQLDynamicTable=REPLACE(STRING_AGG(S,' '),@TableName, '##TempDynamic') FROM #DynamicSQL ----->Create TempTable for SQL Server 2017 and upper version

SELECT  @SQLDynamicTable=STUFF((
         SELECT ' ' + s
            FROM #DynamicSQL 
            FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, '')


SET @SQLDynamicTable = REPLACE(@SQLDynamicTable,@TableName, '##TempDynamic')
PRINT @SQLDynamicTable
EXEC (@SQLDynamicTable)
SET @SQLDynamicRows = 'INSERT INTO ##TempDynamic SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName
EXEC(@SQLDynamicRows)
SELECT * FROM ##TempDynamic
WHERE Deleted IS NULL

GO 
EXEC DynamicSQL 'TargetTable1'



    +------+---------+
    | Col1 | Deleted |
    +------+---------+
    |    2 | NULL    |
    |    4 | NULL    |
    +------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try to create the procedure I get the following errors:
`Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DynamicSQL, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure DynamicSQL, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: I think you are using lower version then the SQL Server 2017 for this reason, I edited the query. STRING_AGG function is not supported lower version of the SQL Server 2017

Comment: OK, I managed to create the stored procedures. Thanks! Now how do I use their results as a table inside my queries?

Comment: SELECT * FROM ##TempDynamic statment in your queries.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Would I need to execute the stored procedure first and then execute a query that uses ##TempDynamic? Because if that is the case, then it is not really what I am after. I need the existing queries in my code to keep working the way they are by simply changing the table name with somwyhing like "MyFunction('TableName')".

Comment: Yes , you should execute the stored procedure before to select , me and other contributers mentioned about it.The main reason is , your table structures are not same.